# PHP- Conditional statement (how to prevent a certain type of record from being inserted)

Tags: php

I am building a booking system but require some help with the following type of scenario. For example, if someone has an equipment booked from 00:00 to 06:00 on a certain day, then someone tries to book the same equipment on the same day between 01:00-05:00, how do I go about stopping this from happening?

I have tried everything to stop this kind of scenario from happening, but unfortunately, the system still allows it to happen. Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $equipment=$_POST['equipment'];
     $start=$_POST['start'];
     $end=$_POST['end'];
     $notes=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $_POST['notes']);
     $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;

     //This code inserts the record
     $sqlinsert="insert into bookings (equipment,start_time,end_time,notes,selected_date,date_added) values ('".$equipment."','".$start."','".$end."','".$notes."','".$eventdate."',now())";
     $resultinsert=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlinsert);

     if($resultinsert){
         echo "<span class='go'> &nbsp;Booking was successful&nbsp; </span>";
     }
 }


 ?>
```

For example, I have tried the following:

```
if($start>$start && $end<$end) {
 echo "not allowed";
}
```

Yet the record is inserted into the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the same variables.  You're going to need to check the database for times which overlap instead.

This should help: [Check if two times overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098541/check-if-two-times-overlap)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is appreciated.

Comment: You need to query your database to check for any existing bookings. If one exists, you do not allow any more reservations. You can use MySQL's BETWEEN and query for both the start date and the end date. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Example for your case:

    SELECT * FROM `bookings` 
    WHERE  (<YOUR_START_DATE> BETWEEN start_time AND end_time);

Do not allow more bookings to start when a booking is still active.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such instead of posting it as an answer

Comment: @Machavity For some reason I don't have the duplicate option for marking a flag.  Not sure if I lack the permission or what.

Comment: @Bing It won't appear on this question now (since it's closed) but it can be found under the `Should be Closed` flag

Comment: @Marius S: Thank you for your help. But unfortunately, nothing has worked for me. I have tried implementing the solution have you suggested, but still could not get the record to stop being inserted. I tried this: "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE selected_date BETWEEN start_time AND end_time" but the database still inserts the record. I also tried creating a new variable, but nothing has worked.

Comment: @dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd you need to put an if statement after querying with my select. If a row is returned, do not execute the insert.

Comment: @Marius S. Thanks for your response. I tried doing this but nothing worked:  $sql="SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE selected_date BETWEEN start_time AND end_time'";
     $result= mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql);
     $results=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if($results>0) {
   echo "<span class='no'> Not allowed </span>";
   Unfortunately, it still did not work

Comment: @dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd “selected_date” has to be a real date(sanitized, of course). i.e. 2017-11-05 18:57:00

Comment: @Marius S: Hi. I have managed to finally solve the problem. The key was to use the variable names in the mysql query. For example, rather than start_time>start_time, I had to use $start>start_time. This solved the problem. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to point out. Make sure to sanitise $start.